# Marklogic PDF documents search

Tags: marklogic

I am creating a MarkLogic search where the end user can search for a string and get pdf document results. I have created a database and uploaded the files in PDF format with appropriate permissions. Here the problem is with my search where it is not returning results in PDF format instead it is returning in XML and XHTML format.

Could someone please advise what can be done here for the search to return only pdf documents?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In past projects, I've had the PDF file and a separate XML document of that PDF (including the URI of the PDF to download). I search against the XML representation and format the results to include a link to download the original PDF. Depending on where/how the PDF is stored, you may need to do something to facilitate serving the PDF from a url.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Could you please also advise how to prepare XML document which includes URI of PDF. Is there any pre defined commands? Please advise.

Comment: I don't think there's anything predefined. You might be able to use a naming convention to build a uri to the original document...let me try to illustrate...

Comment: You have a pdf file called "foo.pdf" that is ingested into MarkLogic. Somehow you've either converted this to xml or used CPF to create an XML document in the database.

What you would need to do is save "foo.pdf" as a binary in the database in addition to the xml (searchable) version. That XML file could contain a uri to where the binary is stored. That requires changing the xml. Or give the binary a URI like "/binary/foo.pdf" and the xml "/xml/foo.xml"

This would allow you build a link that replaces "/xml/" with "/binary/" in the result uri to point to downloading the binary...